# Weird string being prepended in IE10

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, browser, internet-explorer-10

I just encountered the most obscure bug ever.

this string is being pre-pended before  every css/js url served from a local directory

`(F(fZrx2F3_LKJzMBHxhfgtqZvrP_nz_3hbClIBtNVyCXXPiCJUbY7peFKF4WLGBlTcQSRW4Wpk19ymBr_HjdDzNNKynOxUX5Bf2De9fsIuBvZTEgA8HzzjD_LNTx9bYyKqGqyOm0vPWPCf8MyhBpWwbs38mFfzOTSl01XnTzxLYx9B4AXN_E9qgMlMAnJLWD_00))`

ONLY in IE 10 here is a screenshot of the [header of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UV59.png)

i'm ruining on asp.net mvc 3 stack.

The weird thing is that the resources do load with this thing as a prefix

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your web.config make sure that you are not using cookieless forms authentication:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" cookieless="UseCookies" />
</authentication>
```

Setting `cookieless="UseCookies"` ensures that cookies will be used and users won't be tracked by prepending the ticket in the url. IIRC there was a bug in some older versions of .NET where IE10 User Agent wasn't known and the framework assumes that it doesn't support cookies.

And if you are using ASP.NET Session same stands true (you should force it to use cookies):

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="UseCookies" />
```